# js, call parent funciton through prototype

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

May I ask how can I call function c on below situation?? Thank you very much for your advice.

```
    var Foo = function(el){}

    Foo.prototype.d = function(){ 
        // I want to call function c here, how can I do??
    };


    $.fn.a = function(){
        return { 
            b: new Foo(this)
       };
   };

   $.fn.a.prototype.c = function(){ alert(1); };  //function c

   $(el).a().b.d()   <-reach c...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an instance of `a` that was constructed with the new keyword. So you will have to use `call` or `apply`.

```
Foo.prototype.d = function(){ 
    $.fn.a.prototype.c.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

This will run `c` on the `Foo` instance - is that what you want? If you just want to call the function without an specific execution context you can use `$.fn.a.prototype.c()`.

This probably isn't the best way to architect this - if you want to call it as a member function of Foo don't add it as a member function of `$.fn.a`.